# JAVA : Open file in default editor and jump to line number

Tags: java, file

is there any way in Java to open a file in default text editor and jump to line number? Only file name and line number will be input from user.

I am able to open file in default editor using following code

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().edit(new File(filename));
```

But I want to jump to particular line number.

Comment: Jumping to line is program dependent, thus you won't be able to do this in a generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

// ...

    public void solve() {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice screen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot(screen);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int lineNumber = 15;     // your line number

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().edit(new File(filename));
            Thread.sleep(100L);
            for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++) {
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                Thread.sleep(10L);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You must use Thread.sleep, because the file should boot, and a quick key pressing is bad. We click on the down arrow key several times.

Comment: I would not recommend this solution because so much can go wrong while scrolling to line 5000 when you change focus to another window. But I really like the creativity of this approach +1

Answer (score 2):

You will need to start a specific text editor that allows you to jump to a line. Like notepad++.

```
notepad++ FILENAME -n73
```

But often used default text editors like notepad (windows) or gedit (linux) does'nt have such a parameter.

Comment: above command worked for notepad++. But I wanted make my application editor independent. Example: If user makes UltraEditor as its default editor then it doesn't have such parameter.